# Face not visible after changing wireframe to false

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to draw a house, for which I created faces. I had `MeshBasicMaterial`'s `wireframe` set to `true` while I was making it, but when I wanted to add textures to it, I got errors. For troubleshooting that, I changed `wireframe` to `false`, to see what was wrong. Three of my faces were not getting drawn. With `wireframe` set to `false`:
[image]

And when it is `true`:
[image]

I have tried drawing the missing faces with wireframe set to true, and I see them getting drawn. But when I change the parameter to false, it doesn't draw the face.

My code is below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Textures</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body style="font-family:georgia;">

  <script src="http://www.erobo.net/scripts/javascript/33/scripts/three.min.js"></script>

  <div style="width: 580px; height:580px; margin: 0 auto; font-family:georgia;">
    <h2><i>Textures</i></h2>
    <b>My Name</b> [
    <text style="font-family:lucida console; font-size:14px">My_Name@email.com</text>]
    <br>
    <hr>
    <form id="myForm">

      <input type="button" onclick="clearScreen()" value="Clear" style="width: 50px; height: 25px; background-color:lightgrey">
    </form>
    <br>

    <div id="divContainer" style="float:left; width:600px; height:400px; border:2px solid blue;">
      <script>
        var container = document.getElementById("divContainer");
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(container.offsetWidth, container.offsetHeight);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  var aspectRatio = container.offsetWidth / container.offsetHeight;
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-aspectRatio * 100 / 3, aspectRatio * 100 / 2, 100 / 2, -100 / 3, -1000, 1000);
  camera.position.set(20, 10, 20);
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);

  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  var axesGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    //map: texture, 
    //overdraw: 0.5,
    color: 0xFF0000,
    wireframe: true
  });

  var axesMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x00FF00
  });

  axesGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
  axesGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 160));
  axesGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
  axesGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 160, 0));
  axesGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
  axesGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(160, 0, 0));

  geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 30), new THREE.Vector3(0, 30, 30), new THREE.Vector3(0, 30, 0));
  geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(70, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(70, 30, 0), new THREE.Vector3(0, 30, 0));
  geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(70, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(70, 0, 30), new THREE.Vector3(70, 30, 30), new THREE.Vector3(70, 30, 0));
  geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(70, 30, 30), new THREE.Vector3(0, 30, 30), new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 30), new THREE.Vector3(70, 0, 30));
  geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 30, 30), new THREE.Vector3(0, 40, 15), new THREE.Vector3(0, 30, 0));
  geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 30, 0), new THREE.Vector3(70, 30, 0), new THREE.Vector3(70, 40, 15), new THREE.Vector3(0, 40, 15));
  geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 30, 30), new THREE.Vector3(70, 30, 30), new THREE.Vector3(70, 40, 15), new THREE.Vector3(0, 40, 15));
  geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(70, 30, 30), new THREE.Vector3(70, 40, 15), new THREE.Vector3(70, 30, 0));

  geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face4(0, 1, 2, 3));
  geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face4(4, 5, 6, 7));
  geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face4(8, 9, 10, 11));
  geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face4(12, 13, 14, 15));
  geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(16, 17, 18));
  geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face4(19, 20, 21, 22));
  geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face4(23, 24, 25, 26));
  geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(27, 28, 29));

  geometry.computeFaceNormals();
  geometry.computeCentroids();
  var axes = new THREE.Line(axesGeometry, axesMaterial);
  var line = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  //rotation
  line.rotation.x = 0;
  line.rotation.y = 0;
  line.rotation.z = 0;
  axes.rotation.x = 0;
  axes.rotation.y = 0;
  axes.rotation.z = 0;

  scene.add(line);
  scene.add(axes);

  var light = new THREE.PointLight(0x0000ff);
  light.position.set(100, 100, 100);
  scene.add(light);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
      </script>
    </div>
</body>
<br>
<i>Instructions go here.</i>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have checked my code several times, by drawing faces one by one, but three faces out of eight don't get drawn with wireframe set to false.

> Please decrease the `line.rotation.y` from `0` to  `-0.6;` to notice the faces that are not drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because by default it will only draw the "front" of a face. the front is defined by the ordering of the vertices of the face, by default, if you view the face from the front, the vertices will be going anticlockwise:

https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Face_Culling

If you don't want to re-order your vertices so that the winding order is consistent, then an easy solution is to, in your material, set the side to THREE.DoubleSide

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    //map: texture, 
    //overdraw: 0.5,
    color: 0xFF0000,
    wireframe: true,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
```

This will draw both sides of the face, but is less efficent (has to draw twice as many faces)

Comment: Thank you so much. I could never have figured this out by myself.